error reading from server: EOF" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
I have tried installing reinstalling docker/ containered many times but I am getting this error:
Jun 22 23:24:04 infinity dockerd[39130]: time="2024-06-22T23:24:04.104071230+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby

Jun 22 23:24:04 infinity dockerd[39130]: time="2024-06-22T23:24:04.104123876+01:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby

Jun 22 23:24:04 infinity dockerd[39130]: time="2024-06-22T23:24:04.104072342+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.m>

Jun 22 23:24:04 infinity dockerd[39130]: time="2024-06-22T23:24:04.104179065+01:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 jammy.
docker version
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/ciasto/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: v1.0.28
 Version:           26.1.4
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.11
 Git commit:        5650f9b
 Built:             Wed Jun  5 11:28:57 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux


I am trying to launch dev container from within visual studio. I do not understand what makes you say "Why are you attempting to run containerd inside of a container"?

I must have misread the question.
